# jsonwebtoken is returning null in nodejs version 10x

Tags: node.js

jsonwebtoken is not working in nodejs version 10x but working properly in nodejs version 8. token is returning null in version 10x. I had tried to debug the problem but i can't understood why the token is getting null.

please find the code below

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

    var authToken = jwt.sign({ selectedlang: lang, selectedOption: selOption },
        'key', { expiresIn: 90000 });
```

Comment: You can try asynchronous version of it.

Comment: Check selectedlang if it's value is null !